# Encoding issue '&' to '&amp;'

Tags: php, url, curl, encoding

I have been trying to reach an url, through PHP

```
$url = "http://XXXX/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=XXXX&vm_user=$login&memory_mb=$memory&num_cpus=$cpu&eth0_ip=$ip_172&eth1_ip=$ip_192";
```

Now where ever we have '&', it is replacing it with '&amp', because of which I am getting below error.

```
Warning: file(http://XXXX/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=XXXXX&amp;vm_user=vnitin&amp;memory_mb=XX&amp;num_cpus=XX&amp;eth0_ip=XX&amp;eth1_ip=XX): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Here is the code (I tried all possible option)

```
// $ch = curl_init();
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// curl_exec($ch);
// curl_close($ch);
#$newurl = iconv('UTF-8','cp1251',$url);
$payload = file($url);
```

Any idea, how can it be tackled?

Comment: I can't really imagine that a valid `urlencode` gives you 403 errors. These are thrown when you try to access a URI that you need authentication for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: this isn't a 404 - it's a 403, have you passed authentication tokens to the url? / researched if the url needs an authentication token to access? Or perhaps the file is locked for outside users and correct file permissions for open use haven't been correctly configured

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes I have. If I just similarly that url with the correct parameter, then trigger as respective job at Jenkins (Ansible). Which I trigger from php (probably curl)